# Let $A$ be a subset of metric space $X$ and $A^{'}$ be the set of limit points of $A$. Show that $A^{'}$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have done the following as a proof to this:

Assume $A^{'}$ is open.

$\forall x \in A^{'}$, $\quad \exists r>0$ such that $B_{r}(x)\subset A^{'}$.

Also, since $x$ is a limit point of $A$, then $\forall r$ ,$[B_{r}(x)-${$x$}$]\cap$$A$$\neq\emptyset$.

But, $[B_{r}(x)-${$x$}]$\subset$$B_{r}(x)$.

Hence, $\quad \exists x_{0}\in$$B_{r}(x)$ which is in $A$. This implies $B_{r}(x)$ is not completely enclosed by $A^{'}$, which is a contradiction.

So, $A^{'}$ is closed.

I am not sure if this is a correct proof. Correct it if wrong anywhere.

Comment: Open is not the opposite of closed. A set is not a door: it can be both open and closed, or neither, e.g.

Comment: @Henno: Thanks for pointing it out. I am new at analysis and seemed to miss this point.

Comment: Can you please suggest a hint?

Comment: The proof of this can be found in Rudin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that $X \setminus A'$ is open in order to see that $A'$ is closed.

So if $x$ is not in $A'$, this means there is an open ball $B(x,r)$ such that $B(x,r) \cap A \subset \{x\}$ (either empty or the singleton). This is because $x \in A'$ iff for *every* $r>0$, $B(x,r) \setminus \{x\}$ intersects $A$. So if it's not, for some $r$ we have that $B(x,r) \setminus \{x\}$ misses $A$. And this implies what I said.

Now show that all $y \in B(X,r)$ are also not in $A'$, so that $B(x,r) \subset X \setminus A'$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "So if $x$ is not in $A′$, this means there is an open ball $B(x,r)$ such that $B(x,r)∩A⊂{x}$ (either empty or the singleton)"?